# How to change default python to anaconda in windows

Tags: python

I've just installed anaconda and I want to make it my default python.

The problem is, since Python 3.6 is in my AppData folder, when I try to change the path in environment variable, it's not there. I made a PYTHON_HOME path and added it to PATH yesterday, and it was working fine.

However, today when I tried to change it, it's not showing up in the environment variables panel. It's still there though, because when I run "echo %PATH%" in CMD it prints it out.

Is there a way to enable the environment variables to show AppData folders so I can change it to python?

Comment: What do you mean "it's not there"?  Why would it being in AppData make it not appear in an environment variable?

Comment: Are you able to delete your other versions of python on you system?